# onBlur doesn't fire when onClick is triggered programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I'm working with a React component:

```
<div
  ref={tooltipContainer}
  onClick={() => {
    console.log('onclick');
  }}
  onBlur={() => {
    console.log('onblur');
  }}
>
    // Hello
</div>
```

In my componentDidMount hook I'm triggering a click on the div which works as expected (shows the console log).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (someCondition) {
      tooltipContainer.current.click();
    }
  }, []);
```

However when I click anywhere else on the page the `onBlur` event isn't triggered. Shouldn't it since I programmatically clicked on the same element?

Comment: `onBlur` is triggered on `unfocus` and there is no focus in your code.

Comment: The above comment simply means, you have to set focus when you call click event. OnBlur will automatically get triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `div` doesn't have `onBlur` event handler if there is no `contentEditable` or `tabindex=0` provided. But even with those, you'll still need some tweaks.

You want to make `div` focused on click, and clicking on it programmatically doesn't make it focused, so you'll have to add `tooltipContainer.current.focus()` under `click()`

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
myDiv.click();
myDiv.focus();
```

```css
#myDiv {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" onblur="alert('Hello!');" id="myDiv" >Click outside of the box!</div>
```